# Why nested if / else does not work in Pandas dataframe string matching logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe(test1):

```
cons_flag     
Mas
Mas
Wood
Wood
Wood
Mas
Conc
Wood
```

OUTPUT:

```
cons_flag   new_var
Mas MASOM
Mas MASOM
Wood    MASOM
Wood    MASOM
Wood    MASOM
Mas MASOM
Conc    MASOM
Wood    MASOM
```

CODE USED:

```
for x in test1['cons_flag']:
    if x.find('Mas'):
        test1['new_var']="MASOM"
    elif x.find('Wood'):
        test1['new_var']= "WOODEN"
```

My problem is that the `new_var` column values do not update as per my logic.

Comment: Not working , now giving "WOODEN" only in output

Comment: You havn't explained the problem nor the code at all ...

Comment: I want MASOM for MAS and WOODEN for Wood, but I want to use if elif logic only

Answer (score 5):

Do *not* use a `for` loop for this. Instead, you can use `numpy.where` to vectorise your logic.

```
df['new_flag'] = np.where(df['cons_flag'].str.contains('Mas'), 'MASOM',
                          np.where(df['cons_flag'].str.contains('Wood'),
                                   'WOODEN', 'No match'))

#   cons_flag  new_flag
# 0       Mas     MASOM
# 1       Mas     MASOM
# 2      Wood    WOODEN
# 3      Wood    WOODEN
# 4      Wood    WOODEN
# 5       Mas     MASOM
# 6      Conc  No match
# 7      Wood    WOODEN
```

Your logic will always fail, because you are mixing vectorised calculations with non-vectorised conditions. By setting `test1['new_var'] = 'MASOM'`, you are assigning a constant *for the entire series*, not just one row.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but could you please explain why if logic is not working

Comment: @Sandy FWIW, it's also never entering the `elif` statement. `'Wood'.find('Wood')` returns `0` , since `Wood` is at the start of the string. It's essentially testing against a Falsey value

Comment: Hi again, one more query, can I add multiple values for compare e.g df['new_flag'] = np.where(df['cons_flag'].str.contains('Mas','Conc'),'Mas_Conc','None') .    something like that

Comment: Use regex, something like: `df['new_flag'] = np.where(df['cons_flag'].str.contains('Mas|Conc'),'Mas_Conc','None')`